# Alternative to task scheduler on windows that might be allowed by network admins

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I would like to run a command (to sync two folders) each time I log in. Unfortunately I am using a (Windows 10) work computer where access to task scheduler has been tuned off, and I obviously don't have permission to edit the registery. I have also tried [tinytask](https://www.tinytask.net), but our anti-virus software stopped the installation. I do have access to [scoop](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Scoop) and so can download and run many commandline programs, provided they aren't flagged by the anti-virus software.

Are there any alternative routes to automatically running a task at login?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218442/1357527 covers this

Comment: Have you asked your admins for suggestions or assistance? They are responsible for managing your computer, and we cannot suggest things without knowing why they disallow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Natecat in a comment to my question:

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218442/1357527) says to create a shortcut to the batch file and then put the shortcut into

`[D|C]:\Profiles\{User}\‌​AppData\Roaming\Micro‌​soft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startu‌​p`

Comment: That is what I would do.  You should also even be able to put the actual batch file in there.